# SQL Server iterating through time series data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am using SQL Server and wondering if it is possible to iterate through time series data until specific condition is met and based on that label my data in other table?

For example, let's say I have a table like this:

```
Id  Date       Some_kind_of_event
+--+----------+------------------
1  |2018-01-01|dsdf...
1  |2018-01-06|sdfs...
1  |2018-01-29|fsdfs...
2  |2018-05-10|sdfs...
2  |2018-05-11|fgdf...
2  |2018-05-12|asda...
3  |2018-02-15|sgsd...
3  |2018-02-16|rgw...
3  |2018-02-17|sgs...
3  |2018-02-28|sgs...
```

What I want to get, is to calculate for each key the difference between two adjacent events and find out if there exists **difference > 10 days** between these two adjacent events. In case yes, I want to stop iterating for that specific key and put label 'inactive', otherwise 'active' in my other table. After we finish with one key, we start with another.

So for example id = 1 would get label 'inactive' because there exists two dates which have difference bigger that 10 days. The final result would be like that:

```
Id  Label       
+--+----------+
1  |inactive 
2  |active
3  |inactive
```

Any ideas how to do that? Is it possible to do it with SQL?

Comment: Consider editing your question and adding the queries you've tried so far, or maybe a "pseudo-query" of how you think a correct query may look.

Comment: also, you need to  a sample of the other table data, so we know how to link between them, and which is the best approach for your scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with a DBMS you need to get away from the idea of thinking iteratively. Instead you need to try and think in sets. "Instead of thinking about what you want to do to a row, think about what you want to do to a column."

If I understand correctly, is this what you're after?

```
CREATE TABLE SomeEvent (ID int, EventDate date, EventName varchar(10));
INSERT INTO SomeEvent
VALUES (1,'20180101','dsdf...'),
       (1,'20180106','sdfs...'),
       (1,'20180129','fsdfs..'),
       (2,'20180510','sdfs...'),
       (2,'20180511','fgdf...'),
       (2,'20180512','asda...'),
       (3,'20180215','sgsd...'),
       (3,'20180216','rgw....'),
       (3,'20180217','sgs....'),
       (3,'20180228','sgs....');
GO
WITH Gaps AS(
    SELECT *,
           DATEDIFF(DAY,LAG(EventDate) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY EventDate),EventDate) AS EventGap
    FROM SomeEvent)
SELECT ID,
       CASE WHEN MAX(EventGap) > 10 THEN 'inactive' ELSE 'active' END AS Label
FROM Gaps
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID;

GO
DROP TABLE SomeEvent;
GO
```

This *assumes* you are using SQL Server 2012+, as it uses the `LAG` function, and SQL Server 2008 has less than 12 months of any kind of support.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Note, replace @MyTable with your actual table.

```
WITH Diffs AS (
SELECT
    Id
    ,DATEDIFF(DAY,[Date],LEAD([Date],1,0) OVER (ORDER BY [Id], [Date])) Diff
FROM @MyTable)

SELECT 
    Id
    ,CASE WHEN MAX(Diff) > 10 THEN 'Inactive' ELSE 'Active' END
FROM Diffs
GROUP BY Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to share another approach (without a CTE).

```
SELECT 
    ID 
,   CASE WHEN SUM(TotalDays) = (MAX(CNT) - 1) THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Inactive' END Label
FROM (
SELECT 
    ID 
,   EventDate
,   CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, EventDate, LEAD(EventDate) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY EventDate)) < 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END TotalDays
,   COUNT(ID) OVER(PARTITION BY ID) CNT
FROM EventsTable 
) D
GROUP BY ID
```

The method is counting how many records each ID has, and getting the TotalDays by date differences (in days) between the current the next date, if the difference is less than 10 days, then give me 1, else give me 0.

Then compare, if the total days equal the number of records that each ID has (minus one) would print Active, else Inactive.

This is just another approach that doesn't use CTE.